# Component Identification SMT transistor in SOT package

Tags: transistors, identification, repair

I am trying to repair the power board of my Nikon D4 DSLR camera.  I found out that there is a bad transistor on the board.

Can you help me identify it?

[image]

The transistor is really small. I could only see those dots under the microscope.

Here is an image of the board itself:

[image]

Comment: how do you know it's that transistor that's bad? (it's not even obvious to me this *is* a transistor!)

Comment: Take a look at [here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/fr).

Comment: A friend suggested 'FR' points out that it is a PNP transistor and I used my multimeter to confirm that it is open in both directions (I dont know how to explain this in english).

Answer (score 1):

Could be a 2SA1037AK PNP transistor
https://www.rohm.com/products/transistors/bipolar-transistors/standard-bipolar-transistors/2sa1037ak-product